# How to automatically execute a task after JFrame is displayed, from within it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, task

How to automatically execute a task (using a worker thread) immediately after a (class extending) `JFrame` is displayed, while, if possible, maintaining the starting code for that task within the class extending `JFrame`?

All examples I'm finding, and how I've used it myself up to now, only show GUI class extensions with code that *reacts to input* after starting and displaying the GUIs, with any automatic further actions being done *outside* the code that starts and displays the GUI; in other words, what I (do/don't) see is as commented in the example code below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Set the Look and Feel
    //...

    //Create and display the form
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyFrame().setVisible(true); //<--- I never see automatic stuff happening
            //...within here (class). I realize it can be done overriding setVisible(), but
            //...that would be cheating in regards to the intent of this question.
        }
    });

    //In the examples I found, and the way I have done it myself, automatic
    //..."after GUI is displayed" actions, such as a starting a worker that will load
    //...something heavy on startup, while the GUI displays a progressar, are started here.
}
```

Is it possible to execute a task, such as triggering an event, starting a worker, or otherwise executing some unrelated piece of code, within `MyFrame` (any extension of `JFrame`), without doing it within an override of `setVisible()` or other initialization method of the component(s) (in a manner that would otherwise not be done)?

And if it is possible, how to do it?

---

Bonus minor question:
Assuming it's possible, are there any recommendations about where to do it for NetBeans' GUI-builder auto-generated code, or code of similar structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

---

A couple of possible solutions come to mind, for dealing with both; if you need the task to be executed only on the first time (on startup, for example), or for multiple times (every time the window or component is displayed):

- Adding a [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the `JFrame` from within it, and have that initiate the action/worker within `windowOpened(WindowEvent e)`, which is *"Called just after the listened-to window has been shown for the first time"*.
- Adding a [`ComponentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to the `JFrame` from within it, and have that initiate the action/worker within `componentShown(ComponentEvent)`, which is *"Called after the listened-to component becomes visible as the result of the setVisible method being called"*.

Similar solutions with [other listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) are also possible, but these are probably the best methods, and for any odd cases, from these two, you should get the idea of how to implement the other variants.

---

**Bonus answer:**
The best place to add the listeners would be after the initialization of the other components. In NetBeans', the initialization code is auto-generated, contained within a method (`initComponents()`), and is mostly locked (probably to avoid tinkering that would break things related to the visual GUI builder).

Since the listener is not related to any component (other than the frame itself; or the 'base' component you're extending), it's actually a good idea to separate this listener addition from the rest of the initialization code (including other listeners responsible for operations of the sub-components of the GUI), and so NetBeans' locking the initialization codes is a convenient enforcement of this separation that will actually help keep the code clean and readable.

In this case, we still add the listener right after initialization, but in the constructor rather than in the `initComponents()` method; and since "`addSomeListener()`" methods are overridable, and at least in this example, we don't want to accidentally "forget" this code on extensions, we do similarly to the auto-generated code, and wrap our self-pointing "`addSomeListener()`" methods (and other actions, if needed) within our own `initSomething()` method!

Here is a code example:

```
//Within -> public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//This is a mockup worker to simulate some time-consiming loading task that would be performed at startup, with the GUI providing a loading screen...
SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> StartupLoader = new SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Some time consuming task is at " + i + "%...");
        }
        return 100;
    }
};

//This method is used to avoid calling an overridable method ('addWindowListener()') from within the constructor.
private void initSelfListeners() {
    WindowListener taskStarterWindowListener = new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Performing task..."); //Perform task here. In this case, we are simulating a startup (only once) time-consuming task that would use a worker.
            StartupLoader.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...Or something...You decide!
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...Or drink coffee...NVM; always drink coffee!
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...Or do EVERYTHING!
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...Or break the law...
        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...Procrastinate like me!
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            //Do nothing...And please don't notice I have way too much free time today...
        }
    };

    //Here is where the magic happens! We make (a listener within) the frame start listening to the frame's own events!
    this.addWindowListener(taskStarterWindowListener);
}

//The method that adds the listeners that perform the tasks is added in the constructor,
//right after initializing the components (auto-generated method in NetBeans).
public MyFrame() {
    initComponents();
    initSelfListeners(); //
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `Do nothing` comments, you could extend from a `WindowAdapter` instead of a `WindowListener`.

Comment: By the way, `addWindowListener` is still called from within the constructor, only indirectly now. The warning about this situation is pointless though since `MyFrame` is an effectively final class. The warning should go away when you declare `MyFrame` to be `final`, and if the warning is still there, the linter is wrong. (Was it FindBugs or PMD?)

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks for the feedback! I didn't know about `WindowAdapter`. I haven't programmed anything in Java for the past 2 years or so, but if I ever start working with it again, this will be convenient! --- Related to my Java inactivity and regarding the linter; I don't think it was either of those(?), but I can't remember. Either way, the tip on using `final` is also welcome! But for the sake of future-proofing, how would you deal with a non-final case?

Comment: The non-final case is indeed problematic. When the base constructor calls a method that is overridden in a subclass, either that method may not be involved, or you would have to deal with uninitialized fields. I don't remember which one it is, I'd have to look it up in the Java Language Specification, somewhere in the chapter about creating and initializing objects.